# Add N aws_routes to aws_route_table in Terraform module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

A CI/CD pipeline:

1.)  Iinstantiates two AWS VPCs and an AWS VPC Peering Connection using three [Terraform modules](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/index.html).
2.)  Then, the CI/CD pipeline must add an arbitrary number of [`aws_route` objects](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/route.html) to the [`aws_route_table` objects](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/route_table.html) in each of the VPCs that were just instantiated from the modules in an earlier step in the pipeline.

> **What is a clean, elegant, way to add the arbitrary number of new `aws_route` objects to a route table in a VPC that was instantiated from a Terraform Module?**  The module needs to be able to also be instantiated elsewhere without these `aws_route` instances.

I would like to avoid having the automation script simply paste `aws_route` blocks into the code that defines each module and re-applying, because it seems like the modules should be consumed by automation instead of being re-written by automation.

I have thought of creating a new module for `aws_route`, but there is no `count` property in the Terraform `aws_route` object definition, so the script would also have to create a mess while trying to manipulate an arbitrary number of instantiations of an `aws_route` module.

Comment: If I understand what you're doing, I accomplish this via modules (one for routetable, one for route, and one for route_associations) and pass relevant vars between them.